# Why do I get NMinimize::nrnum error?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have this minimization program and although I've restricted my variables to be non negative, I get a nrnum error in the `NMinimize` step. I'm guessing this is what is causing the misaligned yellowish point in the plot (the other ones seem to be right, although it's hard to tell).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}};
qVec = Array[q, 3];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, 3];
optimalweights = 
  Table[Table[qVec /. NMinimize[{qVec^(1/a).A.{surf, 1 - surf}, 
    qVec.onesVec == 1, Thread[1 >= qVec >= 0]}, qVec, 
   Reals][[2]], {surf, 0, 1, 1/10}], {a, {1/2, 2/3}}];
ListPointPlot3D[optimalweights, ViewPoint -> {100, 100, 100} , 
  Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Also, Initially I used `Minimize` and it worked fine for the `a=1/2` case. When I tried  it with `a=2/3` I ended up aborting the evaluation after it had ran for over 24 hours without producing an output.

Comment: Remove `Reals`inside `NMinimize`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I removed it, but the problem persists

Comment: Your code works on v12.2 . Perhaps you should restart your Mtahematica session?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I'm using v11.3. Perhaps is high time I update. Any idea about why ````Minimize```` takes so long?

Comment: `optimalweights` is computed in `0.049824` sec. for me (Mac M1, V13.0.1).

Comment: In V13 a convex optimizer is automatically called on this problem. I believe that method was introduced in V12.2; however, none of the other methods take much more than a second on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing `Reals` inside `NMinimize` your code evaluates

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}};
qVec = Array[q, 3];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, 3];
optimalweights = 
  Table[Table[qVec /. NMinimize[{qVec^(1/a).A.{surf, 1 - surf}, 
    qVec.onesVec == 1, Thread[1 >= qVec >= 0]}, qVec, 
   Reals][[2]], {surf, 0, 1, 1/10}], {a, {1/2, 2/3}}];
ListPointPlot3D[optimalweights, ViewPoint -> {100, 100, 100} , 
  Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]